# Only update added javascript elements on second click

Tags: javascript, html, button, click

I have some Javascript code that gets values from an array that processes a http response from a server and adds buttons to a modal window. So the ids for the buttons come from the array. 
On second click everything is fine and my buttons are added to the modal window. But when I call the function the next time it adds the buttons again, but it should only update the buttons. 
How can I handle it that the function will only update the buttons on second and further clicks?

```
buttonContainer = document.getElementById('modal1');                
        for (i = 0; i < resultContainers.length; i++) {
            newButton = document.createElement('input');
            newButton.type = 'button';
            newButton.value = resultContainers[i];
            newButton.id = resultContainerValues[i];
            newButton.class = 'buttonContainer';
                if (newButton.id == 'true') {
                    newButton.style.backgroundColor = '#8cff1a';
                };
            newButton.onclick = function () {
                alert('You pressed '+this.id);
            };
            buttonContainer.appendChild(newButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the button already exists before you add it in that case.  Since you know the id of the button you're about to create, you can see if there's already a button with that id and just update it instead.

```
var newButton = document.getElementById(resultContainerValues[i]);
if(newButton!=null) {
    newButton.value = resultContainers[i];
} else {
    newButton = document.createElement('input');
    newButton.type = 'button';
    newButton.value = resultContainers[i];
    newButton.id = resultContainerValues[i];
    newButton.class = 'buttonContainer';
    if (newButton.id == 'true') {
        newButton.style.backgroundColor = '#8cff1a';
    }
    newButton.onclick = function () {
        alert('You pressed '+this.id);
    };
    buttonContainer.appendChild(newButton);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your help, but when I load the function for a second time the buttons will be added again. What I want is, that not all the buttons will be added for a second time, but the buttons should be updated, that each of them exists only once. Is there a possibility to do this in an easy way? @kamoroso94

Comment: I think I may be fuzzy on some of the details of your problem.  I made a JSFiddle example that kind of shows what I hope you're looking for.  If not, maybe you can update your question with more details?  https://jsfiddle.net/x5k57o01/

Comment: That really doesn't tell me more about the problem you're having.  You mentioned that the buttons keep getting duplicated.  When are you calling this code and where are you getting the values for the `resultContainers` and `resultContainerValues` variables?

Comment: I´m sorry, I have to be more detailed in my questions.I have a modal which has a few buttons with different options to invoke different functions when clicking on them. E.g. if I click on the button in the modal 'Get State' it invokes the corresponding function where the above mentioned code is part of. This function places then the buttons from the array in the modal which represents different keys of the array. The problem I have is when I´m clicking on the button 'Get State' (in modal) again, the buttons that were created by this function should not be created additionally but only updated.

Comment: As long as the `id`s of the buttons remain the same, you can do just what my example says and check and see if the button already exists.  If so, just update it.  Otherwise, create it and append it to the `buttonContainer`.  I am curious why one of the `id`s is `"true"`.  Is the button with the `id` of `"true"` supposed to change?  Just throwing this out there, but you do know that `id`s are supposed to be unique right?  Are the other `id`s unque, or do they all have the value `"false"`?